# What is the difference between Polygon.contains and Polygon.within?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

The Docstring says:

`Polygon.contains` Returns True if the geometry contains the other, else False

`Polygon.within` Returns True if geometry is within the other, else False

How are they different?

Comment: Further to the answer below, also keep in mind that it is sometimes more convenient to check from one or the other geometry depending on what you are currently doing. e.g. if working with a, then you would call one, whereas if you're working with b, then you'd call the inverse.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They are inverse relationships: `A` contains `B`, and `B` is within `A`.

```
   >>> A.contains(B)
   True
   >>> B.within(A)
   True

   +----------------------------------+
   |                                  |
   |         +----------+             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |    B     |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         +----------+             |
   |                                  |
   |                                  |
   |   A                              |
   |                                  |
   +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: what happens if A overlaps B ? 
why there are two functions? isn't one enough?

Comment: I think neither would be true, since neither shape is wholly within the other. If you mean A and B are essentially the same shape, both would be false. From the manual for [`contains`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.contains) (emphasis mine): "Returns True if the object’s interior contains the boundary and interior of the other object and *their boundaries do not touch at all.*"

Comment: One would be sufficient--you could define `within(self, obj)` as simply `return obj.contains(self)`--but it may be more readable to use one or the other, depending on the context.

Comment: `poly = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)))`
`po = Point((1,1))`

`print poly.contains(po)`
True
`print poly.within(po)`
False

Comment: something is different here.

Comment: `po.within(poly)` should be true, though. You have to switch the caller and the argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Polygon([(0, 0), (100, 0), (100, 100), (0, 100)])
b = Polygon([(0, 0), (50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 50)])
print(a.within(b), b.within(a))
print(a.contains(b), b.contains(a))
```

Output

```
False True
True False
```

To the point:

**contains** is opposite condition of **within**

```
   +----------------------------------+
   |                                  |
   |         +----------+             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         |    B     |             |
   |         |          |             |
   |         +----------+             |
   |                                  |
   |                                  |
   |   A                              |
   |                                  |
   +----------------------------------+
```

In above case:

- A contains B
- B within A